# Pressing F12 In selenium controled window using python and chromedriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to send keys as "F12" to a automatic selenuim chrome window, bellow is What I have Tried so far:

```
actions = ActionChains(browser)
actions = actions.send_keys(Keys.F12)
actions.perform()
```

With The same method When I press tab it works, but it doesn't work with any function key, I have tested it for F5 and F12.

My main aim is to open developer console and then press "Cntrl+Shift+M" to shift the view to Mobile Version, and then automate a few things in Mobile version, As instagram doesn't allow to post from Website, So I am trying to convert the view to mobile version and then upload some photos.

Please Help me out in Pressing these Keys using selenuim and Python.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709587/mark-amery please Have a look at this one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe please see if could help me out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2568341/krokodilko please check and help me out here

Comment: @krokodilko pleae check